# Как правильно выстроить архитектуру сервиса в Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Есть сервис пользователей в котором реализована работа с бэкендом по авторизации, регистрации и так далее.

Алгоритм такой:

Есть метод получения токена из ЛС:

```
getToken() {
        this.token = this.storageService.get('token');
        return true;
    };
```

И проверки этого токена на стороне сервера:

```
tokenVerify() {
        return this.http.post(this.verifyUrl, JSON.stringify({
                token: this.token,
            }
        ),{headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                if(response.json().token == this.token) {
                    this.headers.append('authorization', `JWT ${this.token}`);
                }

            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    };
```

В случае успешной проверки токен будет включен во все хедеры запроса.

А так же метод проверки авторизации

```
checkAuth() {
        if (this.getToken() && this.tokenVerify()) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false
    };
```

+Есть метод получения имени пользователя через токен

```
getMyUserName(): Promise<ICatalogUser> {
    console.log('Получаем имя');
    console.log(this.headers);

    return this.http.get(this.meUrl, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response =>  response.json() as ICatalogUser)
        .catch(this.handleError);
};
```

Главная проблема в том что метод проверки токена асинхронный и метод получения имени асинхронный и когда я пытаюсь в компоненте проверять авторизацию и получать имя пользователя то ничего не выходит из-за того что токена еще нет во время проверки:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getPosts();
        this.checkAuth();
        this.user = this.userService.me;
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Если метод нужен синхронный, то вместо функций введите флаги `currentToken` и `tokenVerified`, затем устанавливайте их при инициализации и проверяйте в любых комбинациях. Если они выведены в `$scope` - интерфейс сможет соответственно реагировать. Если нужен асинхронный, то [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), например.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил, более активно использовать https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then "Promise chaining", когда вы отдаете то что надо для следующего через return и потом его используете, тогда синхронный && превратиться в цепочку асинхронных then().then()

Еще удачно расписано: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/